# Isolate specific HTML elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

OK, what I need may sounds rather complex, but here it is...

Let's say we have the **HTML code below** *(it's still just an example, but it's still quite accurate)* :

```
<div data-role="content" comp-id="jqm-content-6207" id="jqm-content-6207" class="" data-theme="" >

    <!-- New Navigation Bar #1 -->
    <div data-role="navbar" data-position="fixed" comp-id="jqm-navbar-4603" id="jqm-navbar-4603" class="" data-iconpos="top" >
        <ul>

        <!-- New Navigation Bar Item #1 -->
        <li>
            <a href="#" comp-id="jqm-navbar-item-6671" id="jqm-navbar-item-6671" class="" data-icon="home" data-theme="" >
                One
            </a>
        </li>
        <!-- / New Navigation Bar Item #1 -->

        <!-- New Navigation Bar Item #2 -->
        <li>
            <a href="#" comp-id="jqm-navbar-item-4404" id="jqm-navbar-item-4404" class="" data-icon="gear" data-theme="" >
                Two
            </a>
        </li>
        <!-- / New Navigation Bar Item #2 -->
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- / New Navigation Bar #1 -->

    <!-- New Navigation Bar #2 -->
    <div data-role="navbar" data-position="fixed" comp-id="jqm-navbar-4658" id="jqm-navbar-4658" class="" data-iconpos="top" >
        <ul>

        <!-- New Navigation Bar Item #2.1 -->
        <li>
            <a href="#" comp-id="jqm-navbar-item-5321" id="jqm-navbar-item-5321" class="" data-icon="home" data-theme="" >
                One
            </a>
        </li>
        <!-- / New Navigation Bar Item #2.1 -->

        <!-- New Navigation Bar Item #2.2 -->
        <li>
            <a href="#" comp-id="jqm-navbar-item-2843" id="jqm-navbar-item-2843" class="" data-icon="gear" data-theme="" >
                Two
            </a>
        </li>
        <!-- / New Navigation Bar Item #2.2 -->
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

First-off, the core idea is : when the user clicks an item with the `comp-id` attribute set, then add class `msp-selected` just to this specific element (and remove it from all other elements).

**This is how I'm handling this specific part :**

```
function removeAll()
{
    $("*").each(function() {
        if ($(this)!==undefined) {
            $(this).removeClass("msp-selected");
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready( function() {
    $('[comp-id]').bind('click', function(event) {
        removeAll();
        $(event.target).addClass('msp-selected');
    });
});
```

So, as you may already have guessed it's like a way of "selecting" item (by clicking on them) from the HTML document.

**Now, here's the catch :**

***How could I make it so that the "selection" is progressive?***

What I mean...

**When the user first clicks on the Navigation Bar :**

- Check if the first `div` with `comp-id` is selected (has the class `msp-selected`). If not, select it.
- If the first `div` is already selected, then go one level deeper looking for `comp-id`, and select that one.

---

So, any ideas?

How would you do it?

---

**P.S.** When one clicks on the `<a>` of a navigation item, what specific item receives the event? 
Is it the `<div data-role=\"navbar\">` or the navigation bar item? No matter what, from all these items, I want to select the outermost - not being currently selected. Next time, when the user clicks again and e.g. the navigation bar *is* selected, then unselect it and select it's child (go deeper).

---

**EDIT :**

**When trying :**

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('[comp-id]:not(.msp-selected)').on('click', function(e) {
        removeAll();
        $(this).addClass('msp-selected');

    });
});
```

**What I'm getting when clicking on navbar-item is :**

```
Selected Div : jqm-navbar-item-8421
Selected Div : jqm-navbar-8598
Selected Div : jqm-content-2860
Selected Div : jqm-page-3363
```

So, basically it just "selects" the outermost container. Which is wrong... Next time the user clicks, the content should selected - then the navbar and then the navbar-item....

Comment: what is the end goal here? you're explaining us how you're trying to do things but I'm sure there's a much better way to do it, you want to mark both the link and the parent div with your `msp-selected` class on click?

Comment: @koala_dev No, I'm wanting to select **the "outer"-most not-yet-selected element** (with `comp-id` set). Then select the next (at a deeper level), not-selected element. And so on. Only one item is to be selected at any time... :-)

Comment: @koala_dev Please have a look at my "P.S." at the original question... I hope it's quite helpful as to what I'm trying to do. :-)

Comment: I read it but still I don't quite understand what you mean with the selection being progressive. So you want to handle the click event on your navbar links but the one that is clicked is not necessarily the one that is going to be selected? you want to maintain the order for the selected items?

Comment: @koala_dev Simply put : if you try the above example and you want to select an *exact* item (item means with `comp-id` set) and get that `comp-id` (in the console.log? doesn't really matter), you'll notice it's all messed up. You're clicking on something, and what you get is something else (or `undefined`).

Comment: The problem is the the click event bubbles up, that means that a click in a link triggers a click in the navbar and a click in the content, if you want to handle only clicks on the links, you need to use `a` in your selector, check this http://jsfiddle.net/aw6SC/

Comment: @koala_dev Thanks a lot for all the effort. However : what if we want to generalise it a bit and include also non `a`-dependent `comp-id` items?

Comment: I just don't see how that would work with the markup you provided, I mean you cannot click on the navbar or the content directly, if what you want is to reference the parents of the clicked element with the `comp-id` attribute you can do this http://jsfiddle.net/aw6SC/1/

Answer (score 0):

You may write a function like that (i am not sure if the syntax is correct)

```
  function onclick(sender)
  {
      if(type of sender == null )
      {
           return;
      }
      if(sender.className=="selected")
      {
           onclick(sender.childElement[0]); 

           // OR If you need all children to be selected,

           // for( var i =0; i<sender.childElement.count; i++)
           //    onclick(sender.childElement[i]); 


      }
      else
      {
           sender.className="selected";
      }
  }
```